# Office Add-in Manifest Changes

Tags: excel, office-js

I have developed a sample Excel Add-in with two Buttons in the Ribbon.On the click of first button, an HTML page is getting displayed in the Task Pane. On the click of the second button, the contents of the task pane is getting updated (another HTML page is getting rendered).

The add-in was working fine for older version of Excel 2016 for Mac until I updated it to 16.7. After updating, clicking the second Button no longer updates the page in the Task Pane.

Is there any change that I need to make in the manifest to make sure that the add-in works properly in the latest version of Excel 2016 for Mac?

Control Definitions from Manifest:

```xml
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="SmartView.ButtonPanelApple">
    <Label resid="residLabelPanelLogin" />
    <Supertip>
        <Title resid="residLabelPanelLogin" />
        <Description resid="residToolTipZone" />
    </Supertip>
    <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon_login_16" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon_login_32" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon_login_80" />
    </Icon>
    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
        <TaskpaneId>MyPane</TaskpaneId>
        <SourceLocation resid="residLoginUrl" />
    </Action>
</Control>
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="SmartView.ButtonPanelOptimize">
    <Label resid="residLabelPanelOptimize" />
    <Supertip>
        <Title resid="residLabelPanelOptimize" />
        <Description resid="residToolTipMode" />
    </Supertip>
    <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon_optimize_16" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon_optimize_32" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon_optimize_80" />
    </Icon>
    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
        <TaskpaneId>MyPane</TaskpaneId>
        <SourceLocation resid="residLogoutUrl" />
    </Action>
</Control>
```

Comment: I have technique as mentioned in the below document - 

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/action#xsitype

The technique is working fine upto Excel. 15.9 . but after updating to Excel 16.7 , the technique is not working anymore. Is there any specific reason behind it ? Any changes needed to be done in the manifest file for the same ?

Comment: Could you add the button definitions from your manifest?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft - PFB the actions definitions of both the buttons -

<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">     <TaskpaneId>MyPane</TaskpaneId>
<SourceLocation resid="residLogoutUrl" />
</Action>

<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
<TaskpaneId>MyPane</TaskpaneId>
<SourceLocation resid="residLoginUrl" />
</Action>

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft - <Control xsi:type="Button" id="SmartView.ButtonPanelApple">
<Label resid="residLabelPanelLogin" />
<Supertip>
<Title resid="residLabelPanelLogin" />
<Description resid="residToolTipZone" />
</Supertip>
<Icon>
<bt:Image size="16" resid="icon_login_16" />
<bt:Image size="32" resid="icon_login_32" />
<bt:Image size="80" resid="icon_login_80" />
</Icon>
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
 <TaskpaneId>MyPane</TaskpaneId>
<SourceLocation resid="residLoginUrl" />
</Action>
</Control>

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft - 
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="SmartView.ButtonPanelOptimize">
<Label resid="residLabelPanelOptimize" />
<Supertip>
<Title resid="residLabelPanelOptimize" />
<Description resid="residToolTipMode" />
</Supertip>
<Icon>
<bt:Image size="16" resid="icon_optimize_16" />
<bt:Image size="32" resid="icon_optimize_32" />
<bt:Image size="80" resid="icon_optimize_80" />
</Icon>
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
         <TaskpaneId>MyPane</TaskpaneId>
<SourceLocation resid="residLogoutUrl" />
</Action>
</Control>

Comment: This looks right to me. Could you try removing the `TaskpaneId` element and see what effect that has?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft - If i remove the taskpane id's , then the second URL is getting opened in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's because of the security patch.

> Place the add-in in a Trusted Location or make the location trusted
>   where you have stored your addin.
>   **File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Locations**

P.S Unfortunately, Trust Center is a Windows-only feature of Microsoft office and hence the solution is limited to windows OS.

Check for similar settings or you can uninstall the security patch that was updated recently.

Comment: I am using Excel 16.7 for mac. I am not able to find "Options" under File tab.

Comment: I am side-loading the add-in in Mac.

https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac

But the problem remains.